# Is it possible to switch characters during gameplay?

Tags: resident-evil-6

I am currently having a play on the new Resident Evil 6 demo on PS3.

When you start a new campaign, you get to select from a choice of two characters to play as (and depending on which campaign you choose, the character choices vary). Is it possible to switch to the other character during gameplay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player characters from each scenario will have their own partners which are controlled by either the computer AI or another human player via local or online multiplayer. When playing in single player, the player can allow another player to join in online at any time and inventories are now kept seperate from each other.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil_6#Gameplay)

So basically no you can't switch but if you're hardcore you could buy another PS3, hook it up the local network and with the 2nd character with your feet :P

Comment: Related, so I don't think it's worth asking separately - I heard a rumor that in online multiplayer, when you hit a point when the campaign crosses with another pair of characters, it'll actually connect you with another pair of real players hitting the same point in their campaign (so on-the-fly temporary 4 player co-op).  Any truth to that?

Comment: @Shinrai that sounds like Journey. Except with guns and zombies. And without the emotional depth.